# How to convert a date with a specific format without loosing the date type in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a list of columns I need to convert to date without loosing the date type format. To convert to date one could use `df1[col] = df1[col].astype('datetime64[ns]')` which gives an actual date type but if I want it to be of type `'%m/%d/%Y'` it is often suggested on here that one does this: `df1[col] = df1[col].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` but in excel this is now recognized as a string type and not a date type.

I have gone through many posts and searched online to find a solution to this problem and there must be one.

Here is my code I have that is giving the incorrect types that I do not want:

```
convert_date_cols = ['CutoffDate', 'ModEffectiveDate', 'IOExpirationDate', 'FirstRateAdjustmentDate', 'GF_Service_Xfer_Date', 
                    'BPODate', 'FirstPaymentDate', 'MaturityDate', 'NextRateAdjustmentDate', 'NextPaymentAdjustmentDate',
                    'ModFirstPayDate', 'ModMaturityDate', 'REO Date', 'FCDate', 'BK Date', 'Fico Score Date']

for i, col in enumerate(convert_date_cols):
    df1[col] = df1[col].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    df1[col] = df1[col].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to solve a contradiction in terms.  The code you posted *explicitly* changes the datetime variable to a string representation.  It's not reasonable to expect Excel to treat it as a date for you.  Note, however, that most progress depends on wanting something "unreasonable", and making it happen.

I suspect that your actual problem is to make the spreadsheet display the date in the desired format.  To this end, do not blindly accept the automatic set-up in your excel file.  Write a little extra code to specify the column display format to be what you want.  See the Excel documentation for details.  Then look to see how much of that control you can grab through the Python interface.

Comment: Your suspicion is indeed correct, are you suggesting to use a different method to change the dates?

Comment: No, I suggest that you format the column as a whole.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to do? I need it to be in the format specified without converting it to a string. If you know the answer please provide a solution.